# Dataflow DirectRunner to write to gs://storage_bucket

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow

My test pipeline works ok when running on the google cloud, it saves the files in a Google cloud storage bucket. When running the pipeline locally it does get the data input from a Google cloud storage bucket correctly but refuses to save the output data to a Google cloud storage bucket.

Is this supported at all? Are there any specific settings to be made to make this work?

Any hints are very welcome!

Comment: Yes, this is supported. To help debug your issue, you'll need to include more information about exactly how you're trying to do it (relevant parts of your code) and exactly what errors you're getting (detailed, full printouts of error messages) - merely knowing that your code doesn't work is not enough information to help you fix it.

Comment: "yes", thanks, that's the hint I need, I'll try a bit more and update this question if it wasn't enough.

Comment: It did work in some ways, but didn't in others. I pinned down one way that doesn't work, please see my other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46329286/writing-to-google-storage-buckets-with-tensorflows-tfrecordwriter