# Writing to Google storage buckets with TensorFlow's TFRecordWriter

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataflow

How can I make writing to Google storage buckets work for tensorflow's TFRecordWriter?

tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter is aborting when writing to gs bucket:

```
with tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter(filename) as f:
    f.write(example.SerializeToString())
```

gives the error:

```
> tensorflow/core/platform/cloud/http_request.cc:334] Check failed:
> that->post_body_read_ <= that->post_body_buffer_.size()  Abort trap: 6
```

And then completely shuts down the python kernel.
It does work correctly when writing to a local file.
I'm (bound to) using python 2.7 and tensorflow 1.2, I further use Mac and Google SDK 172.0.0.